# ctest does not invoke build type specific tests

Tags: cmake, automated-tests, ctest

I am trying to create a CMake project where I want to execute tests depending on the build type.
E.g. if I do a performance build, I want to run performance tests, etc.

I found that add_test provides the `CONFIGURATIONS` parameter for that purpose. However if I provide a build type there, `ctest` does not find any tests.

Here's a minimalistic `CMakeLists.txt` reproducing the behaviour.

```
project (test NONE)
include (CTest)

add_test (NAME test
  CONFIGURATIONS Release
  COMMAND cowsay)
```

In shell:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. 
cmake --build .
ctest
```

Output:

```
Running tests... 
Test project /home/phil/cmaketest/build 
No tests were found!!!
```

If I run

```
ctest -C Release
```

I get the desired behaviour, i.e. the test is executed, but I would rather not have to type the `-C Release` by hand.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this indented behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

The `add_test (... CONFIGURATIONS ...)` is exactly for the purpose to later run tests for a specific configuration with `ctest -C ...`.

So yes, this is intended. The reasoning is that this supports both single- and multi-configuration build environments in the same way.

If you want to support only single-configuration environments you could do:

```
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Release")
    add_test (
        NAME test
        COMMAND cowsay
    ) 
endif()
```

Comment: The strange thing with this is that the different tests need different compile/link flags in build step, but I can do something like doing a release build with `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. ; cmake --build .` and then start a code coverage test with `ctest -C Coverage`. But this should clearly be disallowed. But with my current setup it just gives meaningless results.